# Как преобразовать php в байткод с целью сокрытия сорца?

Tags: php, защита, обфускация

Подскажите бесплатные, не сырые решения. На Ioncube у меня нет желания платить 200 бкс/мес.

Comment: Таких нет, и скорее всего сама проблема скрытия исходников на самом деле перед вами не стоит.

Comment: не стесняйтесь своего кода.

Comment: 2дедушка: причем здесь не стесняйтесь? Нужно защитить исходник, чтобы в случае взлома сайта нельзя было слить сорец, а также чтобы при разработке было доступно только апи, но само ядро не доступно.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative PHP Cache, eAccelerator. Оба бесплатны.

Comment: А как же скрытие исходников?